# execute_values with SELECT statement

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am using table merging in order to select items from my db against a list of parameter tuples. The query works fine, but `cur.fetchall()` does not return the entire table that I want.

For example:

```
data = (
    (1, '2020-11-19'),
    (1, '2020-11-20'),
    (1, '2020-11-21'),
    (2, '2020-11-19'),
    (2, '2020-11-20'),
    (2, '2020-11-21')
)
        
query = """
    with data(song_id, date) as (
        values %s
    )
    select t.*
    from my_table t
    join data d 
    on t.song_id = d.song_id and t.date = d.date::date
"""
execute_values(cursor, query, data)
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

In practice, my list of tuples to check against is thousands of rows long, and I expect the response to also be thousands of rows long.

But I am only getting 5 rows back if I call `cur.fetchall()` at the end of this request.

I know that this is because `execute_values` batches the requests, but there is some strange behavior.

If I pass `page_size=10` then I get 2 items back. And if I set `fetch=True` then I get no results at all (even though the `rowcount` does not match that).

My thought was to batch these requests, but the `page_size` for the batch is not matching the number of items that I'm expecting per batch.

How should I change this request so that I can get all the results I'm expecting?

## Edit: (years later after much experience with this)

What you really want to do here, is use the `COPY` command to bulk insert your data into a temporary dataframe. Then use that temporary dataframe to merge on both your columns as you would a normal table. With psycopg2 you can use the `copy_expert` method to perform the `COPY`. To reiterate (according to this example) here's how you would do that...

Also... trust me when I say this... if SPEED is an issue for you, this is by far, not-even-close, the fastest method out there.

*code in this example is not tested*

```
df = pd.DataFrame('<whatever your dataframe is>')

# Start by creating the temporary table
string = '''
    create temp table mydata as (
        item_id int,
        date date
    );
'''
cur.execute(string)

# Now you need to generate an sql string that will copy
# your data into the db
string = sql.SQL("""
    copy {} ({})
        from stdin (
        format csv,
        null "NaN",
        delimiter ',',
        header
    )
""").format(sql.Identifier('mydata'), sql.SQL(',').join([sql.Identifier(i) for i in df.columns])

# Write your dataframe to the disk as a csv
df.to_csv('./temp_dataframe.csv', index=False, na_rep='NaN')

# Copy into the database
with open('./temp_dataframe.csv') as csv_file:
    cur.copy_expert(string, csv_file)

# Now your data should be in your temporary table, so we can
# perform our select like normal
string = '''
    select t.*
    from my_table t
    join mydata d
    on t.item_id = d.item_id and t.date = d.date
'''
cur.execute(string)
data = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: What happens if you do an `outer join`?

Comment: Also, I don't think I understand why you're using `execute_values` here anyway. That assists with batch inserts, but I don't think it does anything to selects?

Comment: I added `FULL OUTER JOIN` and the request does go through and returns what I want. But this is just the way I was recommended to do it. If you have a better way to write this with just a `cur.execute` then I'd appreciate it! I tried doing it that way but I kept getting syntax errors so that's just my inexperience with SQL...

Comment: What were the syntax errors?

Comment: If I do the exact same query (with the `FULL OUTER JOIN`) as `cur.execute(query_string, data)` then I get a `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: @roganjosh actually I should be using `INNER JOIN` because I only want to return rows that are in the list of tuples that I am querying.. I think...

Comment: Actually nevermind, `INNER JOIN` only worked when I tested it with a small dataset. When I use it in practice I have the same problem of it only returning the last 4 rows, not the entire query.

Comment: What is the data type for `t.date`? What do get if you run the query manually in `psql`?

Comment: execute many, as far as I understand, will redo the same query multiple times with varying parameters.  so far, so good.  the trouble is, doing so means that when you fetch, you fetch only what was found by the last execution.  it's good for insert/update/delete, not meant for selects.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The types all match up, and the query works as it is written. My current workaround is chunking these tuples by 100, and running this exact query in a `for loop`, and appending the results along the way to an array. This actually works very well in terms of speed, so I'm not super concerned about this problem anymore, but conceptually I feel like it should still be possible.