# Psycopg2 - Query from parameters passed in as tuples

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

If i have a basic query such as:

```
con = psycopg2.connection(**db)
cursor = connection.cursor()
dummyData = (("cheese", "wine") , ("nougat", "oj"), ("sandwich", "juice"))
sql = """ select * from meals where (food, drink) in %s """
cursor.execute(sql, (dummyData,))
```

This will give me any rows where food and drink exactly match one of the tuples in dummy data.

I need to be able to make a query where the food matches the first part of the tuple and the drink DOES NOT match the second part. And without resorting to looping ie:

```
sql = """ select * from meals where food = %s and drink != %s
for d in dummyData:
    cursor.execute(sql, d)
```

The matches must only be inside the particular tuple. Is there a way of doing this without a loop?

I would assume a set up of

```
where meals = ANY(%S) and drink != ANY(%S)
```

would not work as it would basically be checking for all items in each list.

Comment: Your initial example that you say works does not work. Update your question with a working example.

Comment: edited the dummydata param in execute to fix it. (Tested and works)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to join to a VALUES list.  psycopg2.extras provides a helper method to assist with this.

```
sql = """ SELECT meals.* FROM meals JOIN (VALUES %s) f(a,b) ON food=a AND drink!=b"""
result = psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, sql, dummyData, fetch=True)
print(result)
```

I assigned the supplied values columns aliases of "a" and "b", and then referred to them by those aliases in the ON.

Comment: This seems to work. However it suffers from the same issue as a similar thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481947/execute-values-with-select-statement

Namely not all results are returned. Despite the query working properly on a missing result when data is put in to a single query

Comment: You are going to have explain(as update to your question) '...not all results are returned'. Add example data and expected output.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  I can see where you would have a problem with some other queries such as `NOT EXISTS (...)`, but not with this one. (And setting page_size to larger than the supplied list should fix even that problem).  What version of psycopg2 are you using?  Can you give a reproducer for the problem?